# Content moderation - workflows / weird behavior

Tags: 8, workflows

I have set a content moderation workflows for my content type : Draft and Published states.
Pretty basic, i create a content in Draft which is not published, i can change the moderation_state to Published to published it.

But when i do the following workflows : Draft -> Published -> Draft again, the content is still published. Is it a normal behavior ?

My core version is 8.8.3.

Comment: The idea of content moderation is not published or unpublished, but a second version of the content to replace the published version. When you change the content of your new draft it should not affect the published content. Only when you publish the draft again the page gets updated. So I think this is desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a new state called `Needs Review` to mimic draft state at `/admin/config/workflow/workflows`.

[image]

The one thing to note is to check `default revision`. Then set the permissions and you should be able to go from publish to unpublish.

[image]

After the change here is what your configuration should look like.